# Outdoor 50A welder outlet best practices?

Tags: electrical, welding, usa, canada

What's the best practice for installing a code-compliant 50A 240VAC welder plug outlet on an exterior wall? I can run 6/3 90°C wire to the location from an appropriate breaker. Where should conduit be used (along cinder block wall?) and plastic or metal? I presume it's unnecessary with wire running through holes in joists.

Do I have to/should I install a GFCI? The breaker box is old and new breakers are virtually unobtanium so anything like that would have to be installed outside the breaker box.

Comment: Being outside a GFCI is mandatory now.  There are GFCI outlets, but expensive.  Type of panel might be more important.  There are a few names of old panels that are basically stop using and replace right now, yesterday is not soon enough.

Comment: @crip659 It's a Commander QM32200 200A panel. Last time I replaced a single GFCI breaker it was almost impossible to find.

Comment: The panel is one I don't recognize so think it is safe.  Might be able to power the welder from a newer sub panel.  Add the sub panel between the panel and welder.

Comment: Good answer on this question that deals with wire types to use, might save some money.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/253437/power-to-garage

Comment: @crip659: Would a GFCI even work or is the welder too hostile to it?

Comment: @Joshua  That I do not know, but it is code now and needs to GFCI to be legal(inspected, insured).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First and foremost, use a NEMA 6-50 or 14-50 outlet - *never* a 10-50 outlet, which has neutral and does not have ground. (super bad).  For some reason, welder enthusiasts have "adopted" the NEMA 10-30 and 10-50 as their "private socket/plugs".  This is crazy, don't buy into that nonsense. The NEMA 6 series is designed for welders with no neutral.

For Commander breakers, talk to an Eaton dealer. They make a selection of breakers for Commander that are readily available. If you just can't get breakers for it, it's time for a new panel.

If your state has adopted NEC 2020, then any socket will require GFCI protection as of right now.  And as of January 1 2023, even hardwired 240V loads will require GFCI protection.  If you can avoid a socket, you will sidestep the need for a GFCI, as long as your permit is pulled before January 1 2023.

However, electric vehicle supply equipment (EVSE) that is hardwired will *never* require GFCI protection regardless of that deadline. Because *it is* a GFCI (among its other tricks), and you don't need to put a GFCI on a GFCI.

Comment: Just a ha-ha moment.  I assumed that I was using 10-50 for my welder.  A bit of googling proved the saying about not assuming.  Turns out I was using 6-50 all along.

Comment: @crip659 Yeah, that's why your 6-50 socket has been making that grumpy face :)